ExcelJs error Error: Cannot merge already merged cells
I am trying to generate an excel sheet using excelJs. Order has array order items (could be one or more). I want that some information in the order itself are not repeated while iterating over each items in the order item. However, i keep getting excel error  Error: Cannot merge already merged cells.
  async createExcelReport(orders: OrderDocument[], filename: string) {
      try {
        const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
        const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Report');
        const partnersResponse = await lastValueFrom(
          this.partnerClient.send({ cmd: 'GET_ALL_PARTNERS' }, {}),
        );
    
        if (!partnersResponse) {
          throw new Error('Failed to get partners');
        }
        const partners = partnersResponse.data;
    
        const getPartner = (partnerId: string) =>
          partners.find((partner) => partner.partnerId === partnerId) || {
            partnerName: 'Not available',
          };
    
        // Define headers
        worksheet.columns = [
          { header: 'DATE', key: 'DATE', width: 15 },
          { header: 'Customer NAME', key: 'username', width: 25 },
          { header: 'Member ID', key: 'memberId', width: 25 },
          { header: 'Pharmarun User ID', key: 'userId', width: 25 },
          { header: 'Order Number', key: 'orderNumber', width: 20 },
          { header: 'Pharmacy Name', key: 'pharmacyName', width: 25 },
          { header: 'Customer Type', key: 'customerType', width: 20 },
          { header: 'Partner Name', key: 'businessAlias', width: 25 },
          { header: 'Medication', key: 'medication', width: 25 },
          { header: 'Quantity', key: 'quantity', width: 15 },
          { header: 'Cost Price', key: 'costPrice', width: 15 },
          { header: 'Selling Price', key: 'sellingPrice', width: 15 },
          { header: 'Delivery Fee', key: 'deliveryFee', width: 15 },
          { header: 'TAT', key: 'TAT', width: 15 },
          { header: 'Profitability', key: 'profitability', width: 15 },
          { header: 'Dispatched Type', key: 'dispatch', width: 20 },
          { header: 'Dispatched Approved by', key: 'dispatchApprovedBy', width: 25 },
          { header: 'State', key: 'state', width: 20 },
          { header: 'City', key: 'city', width: 20 },
          { header: 'Landmark', key: 'addressId', width: 25 },
        ];
    
        const mergeAndSetCellValue = (
          startRow: number,
          endRow: number,
          column: string,
          value: any,
        ) => {
          if (startRow !== endRow) {
            worksheet.mergeCells(`${column}${startRow}:${column}${endRow}`);
          }
          worksheet.getCell(`${column}${startRow}`).value = value;
        };
    
        // Add data rows
        let currentRow = 2; // Start from the second row (first row is for headers)
        orders.forEach((order) => {
          const startRow = currentRow;
          order.orderItems.forEach((item, index) => {
            const partner = getPartner(item.pharmacyId);
            worksheet.addRow({
              pharmacyName: partner.partnerName,
              medication: item.drugName,
              quantity: item.quantity,
              costPrice: item.costPrice,
              sellingPrice: item.unitPrice,
              profitability: item.unitPrice - item.costPrice + order.deliveryFee,
            });
            currentRow++;
          });
    
          const endRow = currentRow - 1;
          const deliveryAddress = order.deliveryAddress as DeliveryAddressDocument;
          const dispatch = getPartner(order.dispatch);
          const tat = formatMilliSecondsToTime((order as any).tat?.totalTAT || 0) || '-';
    
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'A', order.createdAt);
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'B', order.username);
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'C', order.memberId);
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'D', order.userId);
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'E', order.orderNumber);
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'G', order.customerSource);
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'M', order.deliveryFee);
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'N', tat);
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'P', order.dispatch ? dispatch.partnerName : 'Not available');
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'R', deliveryAddress ? deliveryAddress.state : null);
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'S', deliveryAddress ? deliveryAddress.city : null);
          mergeAndSetCellValue(startRow, endRow, 'T', deliveryAddress ? deliveryAddress.landmark : null);
        });
    
        await workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filename);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('excel error ', error);
      }
    }

I have tried using Set() to keep it unique but still got into this error

can't reproduce. can you include some data and OrderDocument type

most likely startRow !== endRow fails, when orders and orderItems lengths don't match

I was able to fix this. What i did differently was to eradicate the use of merge cells and focus on leaving them empty where i do not want it to show more than once.
async createExcelReport(orders: OrderDocument[], filename: string) {
    try {
      const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
      const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Report');
      const partnersResponse = await lastValueFrom(
        this.partnerClient.send({ cmd: 'GET_ALL_PARTNERS' }, {}),
      );

      if (!partnersResponse) {
        throw new Error('Failed to get partners');
      }
      const partners = partnersResponse.data;

      const getPartner = (partnerId: string) =>
        partners.find((partner) => partner.partnerId === partnerId) || {
          partnerName: 'Not available',
        };

      // Define headers
      worksheet.columns = [
        { header: 'DATE', key: 'DATE', width: 15 },
        { header: 'Customer NAME', key: 'username', width: 25 },
        { header: 'Member ID', key: 'memberId', width: 25 },
        { header: 'Pharmarun User ID', key: 'userId', width: 25 },
        { header: 'Order Number', key: 'orderNumber', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Pharmacy Name', key: 'pharmacyName', width: 25 },
        { header: 'Customer Type', key: 'customerType', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Partner Name', key: 'businessAlias', width: 25 },
        { header: 'Medication', key: 'medication', width: 25 },
        { header: 'Quantity', key: 'quantity', width: 15 },
        { header: 'Cost Price', key: 'costPrice', width: 15 },
        { header: 'Selling Price', key: 'sellingPrice', width: 15 },
        { header: 'Delivery Fee', key: 'deliveryFee', width: 15 },
        { header: 'TAT', key: 'TAT', width: 15 },
        { header: 'Profitability', key: 'profitability', width: 15 },
        { header: 'Dispatched Type', key: 'dispatch', width: 20 },
        {
          header: 'Dispatched Approved by',
          key: 'dispatchApprovedBy',
          width: 25,
        },
        { header: 'State', key: 'state', width: 20 },
        { header: 'City', key: 'city', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Landmark', key: 'addressId', width: 25 },
      ];

      // Add data rows
      orders.forEach((order) => {
        const deliveryAddress =
          order.deliveryAddress as DeliveryAddressDocument;
        const dispatch = getPartner(order.dispatch);
        const tat =
          formatMilliSecondsToTime((order as any).tat?.totalTAT || 0) || '-';

        order.orderItems.forEach((item, index) => {
          const partner = getPartner(item.pharmacyId);

          worksheet.addRow({
            DATE: index === 0 ? order.createdAt : '',
            username: index === 0 ? order.username : '',
            memberId: index === 0 ? order.memberId : '',
            userId: index === 0 ? order.userId : '',
            orderNumber: index === 0 ? order.orderNumber : '',
            customerType: index === 0 ? order.customerSource : '',
            deliveryFee: index === 0 ? order.deliveryFee : '',
            TAT: index === 0 ? tat : '',
            dispatch:
              index === 0
                ? order.dispatch
                  ? dispatch.partnerName
                  : 'Not available'
                : '',
            state:
              index === 0 ? (deliveryAddress ? deliveryAddress.state : '') : '',
            city:
              index === 0 ? (deliveryAddress ? deliveryAddress.city : '') : '',
            addressId:
              index === 0
                ? deliveryAddress
                  ? deliveryAddress.landmark
                  : ''
                : '',
            pharmacyName: partner.partnerName,
            medication: item.drugName,
            quantity: item.quantity,
            costPrice: item.costPrice,
            sellingPrice: item.unitPrice,
            profitability:
              item.unitPrice -
              item.costPrice +
              (index === 0 ? order.deliveryFee : 0),
          });
        });
      });

      await workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filename);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('excel error ', error);
    }
  }

